# PHP array to csv - Always rewrites the file

Tags: php, csv, fputcsv

I'm trying to save 3 variables to a csv file. I get the variables data then I'm creating an array containing them. I can open the file and write it. I would like to store the following data on every page load:
- referer
- user agent
- date

My problem is that on every page load it rewrites the file instead of just inster the new data.

Any idea?
Every comment is appreciated.

```
<?php
```

session_start();

```
if ( !isset( $_SESSION["origURL"] ) )
$_SESSION["origURL"] = @$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];

$referer = @$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$userAgent = @$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$visitorData = array("referer", "userAgent", "date");
$result = compact($visitorData);
print_r($result);

$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');

foreach ($result as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $result, $delimiter = ',', $enclosure = '"');
}

fclose($fp);
exit();
```

?>

Comment: append mode use - `$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'a');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @splah58 says, you must open your file in *append* mode to add data, like this :

```
if( !isset( $_SESSION["origURL"] ))
  $_SESSION["origURL"] = @$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];

$referer = @$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$userAgent = @$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$visitorData = array("referer", "userAgent", "date");
$result = compact($visitorData);
print_r($result);

$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'a'); // 'a' means 'append' instead of 'w' for 'writing' which always delete the file's content

foreach ($result as $fields) {
  fputcsv($fp, $result, $delimiter = ',', $enclosure = '"');
}

fclose($fp);
exit();
```

Comment: You are right! Thank you!
I experienced one more weird behavior. Do you have any idea why does it log 3 times a row in one session?

Comment: That's because the PHP page is loaded 3 times in one session :)

Comment: I mean one page load = 3 lines of data.

Comment: `$result` may contains 3 content

Comment: When I print it I get this:
Array ( [referer] => http://localhost:8088/php-log/ref.html [userAgent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36 [date] => 2016-07-03 18:39:51 )

Comment: I think you're calling this file 3 times, with an `include()` for example

Comment: I have no idea :(
I'm creating an array from variables and I'm using fputcsv in a froeach